# How to convert Module & Function from VB.NET to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm totally new in c#, I wrote my code in VB.NET before but I'm trying to use c# to re-develop my program and as a lesson for learning c#. I tried long time but still can't get a proper conversion from VB.NET to c# , can anyone help me to convert as I will more easier to understand c#, thank you !

This is my code from VB.NET

```
Module GetStaffList

Dim Url As String
Dim CorpID As String
Dim Secret As String
Const ErrCode As String = """errcode"":0,""errmsg"":""ok"""

Function Token(CorpID As String, Secret As String) As String

    CorpID = "wwe1f80304633b3"
    Secret = "Ev7_oVNNbTpzkfcZ_QhX9l0VjZnAQ"

    Dim http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    Url = "https://qyapi.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/gettoken?corpid=" & CorpID & "&corpsecret=" & Secret
    http.Open("get", Url, False)
    http.send()

    If http.Status = 200 Then
        Token = http.responseText
    End If

    If InStr(Token, "access_token") > 1 Then
        Token = Split(Token, ",")(2)
        Token = Split(Token, ":")(1)
        Token = Replace(Token, """", "")
        MainPage.TxtToken.Text = Token
    Else
        Token = ""
    End If

End Function
```

And below is what I trying convert to c# but still hard to do

```
namespace SC_System
```

{
    class MSG
    {
        const string ErrCode = "\"errcode\":0,\"errmsg\":\"ok\"";

```
    public void Token(string CorpID, string Secret)
    {
        var http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP");
        string Url = "https://qyapi.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/gettoken?corpid=" + PDC.CorpID + "&corpsecret=" + PDC.Secret +"";
        HttpWebRequest GetUrl = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
        HttpWebResponse ResponseUrl = (HttpWebResponse)GetUrl.GetResponse();
        if (ResponseUrl.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ResponseUrl.StatusDescription);
            ResponseUrl.Close();
        }

    }

    private object CreateObject(string v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There's no good reason to **ever** call `CreateObject()` anymore even in VB.Net, let alone C#.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, are you saying that to create say COM Objects, one should use System.Activator instead? Or something else?

Comment: @MacroMarc Of course "ever" is hyperbole. More that it's becoming exceedingly rare to find COM objects that either aren't either completely obsolete/redundant (as in this case) or at least already have managed wrapper (which you could argue this also is). And if you're still building your own new ones... just stop.

Comment: *Hard to do is not a question*... we help with specific issues, we are not a code translation service. Please update your post on where you are stuck. Also you are mixing `vb` and `vb6`...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This translates the working parts of the original VB:

```
internal static class GetStaffList
{
    //this doesn't seem to be used right now
    internal const string ErrCode = "\"errcode\":0,\"errmsg\":\"ok\"";

    internal static void Token(string CorpID, string Secret)
    {
        CorpID = CorpID ?? "wwe1f80304633b3";
        Secret = Secret ?? "Ev7_oVNNbTpzkfcZ_QhX9l0VjZnAQ";

        string token;    
        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            token = wc.DownloadString($"https://qyapi.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/gettoken?corpid={CorpID}&corpsecret={Secret}");
        }
        if (token.Contains("access_token"))
        {
            token = token.Split(",")[2].Split(":")[1].Replace("\"", "");
            MainPage.TxtToken.Text = token;
        }
        else 
        {
            token = ""; 
        }
    }
}
```

But you're probably better off actually returning a value, and *not* updating the UI, as was only hinted at in the VB method:

```
internal static string Token(string CorpID, string Secret)
{
    CorpID = CorpID ?? "wwe1f80304633b3";
    Secret = Secret ?? "Ev7_oVNNbTpzkfcZ_QhX9l0VjZnAQ";

    string token;    
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        token = wc.DownloadString($"https://qyapi.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/gettoken?corpid={CorpID}&corpsecret={Secret}");
    }
    if (token.Contains("access_token"))
    {
        return token.Split(",")[2].Split(":")[1].Replace("\"", "");
    }
    return "";
}
```

And then you'd call it like this:

```
string token = GetStaffList.Token(null, null);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
{
    MainPage.TxtToken.Text = token;
}
```

Never have your utility methods or classes directly update the UI.

In the same vein, it's better to write the VB like this:

```vb
Public Module GetStaffList

    Const ErrCode As String = """errcode"":0,""errmsg"":""ok"""

    Public Function Token(Optional CorpID As String = Nothing, Optional Secret As String = Nothing) As String

        CorpID = If(CorpID,"wwe1f80304633b3")
        Secret = If(Secret,"Ev7_oVNNbTpzkfcZ_QhX9l0VjZnAQ")

        Dim token As String
        Using wc As New WebClient()
            token = wc.DownlaodString(string.Format("https://qyapi.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/gettoken?corpid={0}&corpsecret={1}", CorpID, Secret))
        End Using

        If token.Contains("access_token") Then
            Return token.Split(",")(2).Split(":")(1).Replace("""", "")
        End If
        Return ""
    End Function
End Module
```

Finally, you should consider using an [actual JSON parser](https://www.google.com/search?q=nuget%20json&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS751US752&oq=nuget%20json&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1321j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to extract the token value you need from the download result. The `Split()` method is notorious for gotchas with this kind of thing, and actually tends to be *slower* than a dedicated parser.

Answer (score -1):

In VB, a `Function` returns some value. In your code it returns a `string`

- `Function Token(CorpID As String, Secret As String) As String`

  becomes

  ```
  string Token(string CorpID, string Secret){
    // do something...and then
    return "some string value";
  }
  ```

  and needs to `return` some string value. The function name *doesn't* infer a variable of the same name (`Token`) as the return value
- a `Sub` doesn't return anything so:

  `Sub Token(CorpID As String, Secret As String)`

  becomes `void` in c#

  `void Token(string CorpID, string Secret)`

Hopefully should get you going...